# How can I put an Anchor in React.js next to React-router-dom? or there is a better way to put anchors in react.js

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a spa that consists of a homepage, categories, about us and contact us.

They all take you to a different component except categories that should take me to a part of the homepage.

Is there a way how to do it with React-router or is there another way
to do it?

Comment: Questions without code often get closed on SO. Consider adding some relevant code please.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to give feedback without seeing your code.
But if I understood correctly, you want to navigate between the different components using React-Router. 
You can import the Router, Switch and Route from React-Router and then in your toplevel-container component, you would create the different  for each component, making the URL change based on each component, e.g. /about-us, /contact-us, etc.

If you want your categories to be part of your homepage, then you could create another  inside Homepage component, where you want it displayed, if it's only rendered at a specific URL. If you want it displayed at all times, then make the link go to the /homepage URL, same as for the regular homepage component.